# show and hide text and enable disable button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two div with different content. In page reload i would to have one DIV content to display as defualt however by clicking on button the content should change in same DIV content area and the another button also need disable. here is my code Im able to show and hide text but by defualt both text is displayed also both button are active.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utL3Z.jpg)

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('btn').disabled = 'disabled';
            y.style.display = "none";

        }
    }

    function myFunction1() {
        var y = document.getElementById("myDIV1");
        if (y.style.display === "none") {
            y.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            y.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>


<button class="btn btn-primary about" id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Base Solution</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary about" onclick="myFunction1()">Augmented Solution</button>

<div class="col-md-6" id="myDIV">
    <ul class="custom">
        <li>Automation of the elementary CITES permit procedures</li>
        <li>Transparency and accountability in the permit process</li>

    </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6" id="myDIV1">
    <ul class="custom">

        <li>Integration and maintenance of a database of registered facilities</li>
        <li>Extension of national eCITES reporting Automation of other processes to support various business models and national legislations</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked your code a little bit

i've given id to the second button,and merged the two function to one

Link : https://jsfiddle.net/guz2de7h/2/

```
<button class="btn btn-primary about" id="btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">Base Solution</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary about" id="btn2" onclick="myFunction(this)">Augmented Solution</button>
```

```
document.getElementById('btn').disabled = 'disabled';
 var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
 var y = document.getElementById("myDIV1");
 y.style.display = "none";

 function myFunction(btn) {
   var btnid = btn.id;
   if(btnid=="btn2")
   {
    x.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById('btn2').disabled = 'disabled';
      document.getElementById('btn').disabled = false;
   }
   else
   {
   x.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById('btn').disabled = 'disabled';
     document.getElementById('btn2').disabled = false;
   
   }
   
 
 }
```

Comment: you can improve it by changing the first button id because class name and id name are same

Comment: Perfect that works fine for me, I just added color to the disable button to be differentiate form the active one